# How would I use Javascript to order my divs based on their ID?

Tags: javascript, html

What is some Javascript code that will allow me to list out the id names of my divs and then display them in that order without having to actually change the code on my page?

I don't want to just swap two divs at a time to do this, I want a list/array that I can type the order into and it will show in that order.

I have 4 divs (div1, div2, div3, div4)

Thanks =D

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you're asking/trying to do.

Comment: @kinakuta: i'm trying to reorder my divs with javascript rather than moving the code around. I need to do this so I can do something /else/ later.

Comment: How is the desired order of the divs being determined?

Comment: EVENTUALLY, by what is saved in a cookie. They are being moved with a bit of jQuery code I was given.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming HTML like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
    <div id="three">Three</div>
    <div id="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

You could do this with jQuery

```
var w = $('#wrapper').html();
var arr = w.split('\n');

$('#wrapper').html(arr[2] + arr[4] + arr[1] + arr[3]);
```

Changing the order of the array elements as necessary.

NB: I am splitting the html into an array based on the line break `\n`.  It gives a first blank line, as I am collecting from the start of `div#wrapper`.  Therefore `arr[0]` is never used.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/yFEVz/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic Dom element sort. The only JQuery I use here is to collect all the elements within the container and push them to an array. You can remove the jquery, but you would have to convert the nodeList to an array for the sort to work. Cheers!

When doing operations like this using as little JQuery as possible, as well as manipulating/accessing the DOM as little as possible will greatly improve execution time.

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/wATVf/

Comment: Also, unsure what your 'real' ids will be for the divs i provided a simple string sort method as well as a numeric sort method. Note, the string is case insensitive, and the numeric sort strips all non-numbers then sorts on the leftovers. (i.e 1b2 will be seen as 12)

Comment: Also I feel it is important to note, my examples is actually code i've stripped from a project of mine. So it is meant to be encapsulated in a function, you pass in the DOM collection you want to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Give the elements in question ('your divs') a common class and use that to manipulate them as a group -- with jQuery, the code to do so would look something like this:

```
$('.my-divs').each(function (idx, val) {
    // sort your elements here;
    // use something like $(val).is('#your-id') to inspect their id.
});
```

... assuming the HTML for your divs looks something like this:

```
<div id="div1" class="my-divs"> ... </div>
<div id="div2" class="my-divs"> ... </div>
<div id="div3" class="my-divs"> ... </div>
<!-- et cetera -->
```